# Unable to import a class from TypeScript into Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript, import, protractor

Unable to import a class from typescript file into a javascript.

## app.e2e-spec.ts:

```
const outputarray = new Array();
const newObj = Object();
export class Arrayconstructor {
 public arrayvalues() {
    newObj.qid = quoteId;
    newObj.qname = quoteName;
    return outputarray.push(newObj);
    console.log('outputarray value is: ' + outputarray);
  }
}
```

Tried both the options mentioned below. But still unsuccessful.

```
const { Arrayconstructor } = require('./app.e2e-spec.ts');

arrayItems = require('./app.e2e-spec.ts');
```

Erorr:

```
(function (exports, require, module, __filename, __dirname) { import { slowDown } from './utils';
                                                                     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
    at new Script (vm.js:79:7)
    at createScript (vm.js:251:10)
    at Object.runInThisContext (vm.js:303:10)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:657:28)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:637:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:22:18)
```

Test gets executed successfully if I comment the above mentioned import statement.

Comment: You cannot have an import statement inside a function, because you will import all things inside this function and are refered in that function, but outside that function they didn't exists, also, you can't import a .ts file in a .js file and viceversa.

Comment: if you want to import a js file in a typescript file, you only need to change your .js file to a typescript file, but you cannot make the same viceversa, because typescript uses a mixed-in of javascript and java, but javascript only uses javascript not java, so some things like public, abstract and some other things that typescript uses, does not exists in javascript, also explicit types declaration, so it's impossible to import a .ts file in a javascript file, but is possible to import a .js in a typescript file, you only need to change the extension of the file of .js to .ts and will works.

Comment: Also this applies to file member classes, functions, constants, variables and anything that is importable or exportable. This means you can't import a .ts class in a .js file and also, you can't import a .js class in a .ts file.

Comment: Thanks @Riven. I have changed the java-script file into Typescript to import the class and progress further.